# Scrolling Site Issues With Main Nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've built a scrolling homepage for my site that allows users to click a link in the header to scroll down to different sections of the site. I also have external links to new pages that allows users to view different projects.
For whatever reason, it works great, but as soon as I get to one of the project pages, then try to click the home page, or the work links it doesn't work properly. Without creating a second `header.php`,
how can I make the `nav` work globally.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.logo, ul.nav a, #mmenu a, a.mobileLogo').bind('click',function(event){
            var $anchor = $(this);

            href_arr = $anchor.attr('href').split("#");

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $('#'+href_arr[1]).offset().top - 0
            }, 500);   // it was -70                 
            event.preventDefault();
        }); 
     });
});
</script>
```

My links looks like this...

```
    <a href="/#home">Link</a>
    <a href="/#work">Work</a>
```

Any thoughts on how to fix the jQuery so it works on external pages?

Comment: Yes. on your 'external' (every) pages you need to check with JS the *hash* in the URL, if detected simply grab it and apply it to your  animations logic. (Be aware that you might want to override the default browser behavior -> to go to that anchor initially.) Happy googling! You have all those answers already here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `#home` and `#work` don't exist on your product pages, correct? If that's the case then calling `event.preventDefault()` will actually prevent the browser from going back to your home page. Try checking if the element exists before preventing the default behavior. If the element doesn't exist, the browser will visit the link normally. This is one way of doing it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.logo, ul.nav a, #mmenu a, a.mobileLogo').bind('click',function(event){
        var hash = '#' + $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];

        // check if the element exists on your page
        if ($(hash).length) {
            // if so, scroll to it and prevent the default behavior
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 0
            }, 500);
            event.preventDefault();                
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Correct. The home page has sections which the nav is calling. #home #work, #about, #contact. So in the header file the link is calling each of these sections. But once I select a project in the work page, and it goes from www.url.com to www.url.com/project, I can't get back. The navigation doesn't work anymore.

Comment: If I add <a href="www.url.com/#home">Home</a> it does work, but the smooth scroll does not anymore. It doesn't load and then scroll down to the work section for instance. How could I amend that? By the way, thank you for the advice. I removed the preventDefault.